# How can I add a boolean value to a NSDictionary?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit

Well, for integers I would use `NSNumber`. But YES and NO aren't objects, I guess. A.f.a.i.k. I can only add objects to an `NSDictionary`, right?

I couldn't find any wrapper class for booleans. Is there any?

Comment: Just in case, A.f.a.i.k. is as far as I know

Answer (score 164, accepted):

**You use NSNumber.**

It has init... and number... methods that take booleans, just as it does integers and so on.

From the [NSNumber class reference](http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

```
// Creates and returns an NSNumber object containing a 
// given value, treating it as a BOOL.
+ (NSNumber *)numberWithBool:(BOOL)value
```

and:

```
// Returns an NSNumber object initialized to contain a
// given value, treated as a BOOL.
- (id)initWithBool:(BOOL)value
```

and:

```
// Returns the receiver’s value as a BOOL.
- (BOOL)boolValue
```

Comment: Great! I guess internally it stores the bool as 0 / 1?

Comment: @harms is correct.  As an example:  `NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], @"someKey", nil];`

Comment: It is worth pointing out, that there is now a literal syntax for NSNumbers.  

`@YES` is the same as `[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]`

Answer (score 58):

The new syntax since `Apple LLVM Compiler 4.0`

```
dictionary[@"key1"] = @(boolValue);
dictionary[@"key2"] = @YES;
```

The syntax converts `BOOL` to `NSNumber`, which is acceptable to `NSDictionary`.

Answer (score 16):

If you are declaring it as a literal and you are using clang v3.1 or above, you should use @NO / @YES if you are declaring it as a literal. E.g.

```
NSMutableDictionary* foo = [@{ @"key": @NO } mutableCopy];
foo[@"bar"] = @YES;
```

For more info on that:

http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html

Comment: Get a compiler error: Incompatible pointer types initializing NSMutableDictionary * with an expression of type NSDictionary. If you change the declaration to NSDictionary instead, get compiler error: Expected method to write dictionary element not found on object of type NSDictionary *

Comment: The literal will only create an `NSDictionary`, not an `NSMutableDictionary`. So assigning `@YES` to `foo[@"bar"]` is not possible since `@{ @"key": @NO }` is not mutable.

Answer (score 3):

As [jcampbell1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20512/jcampbell1) pointed out, now you can use literal syntax for NSNumbers:

```
NSDictionary *data = @{
                      // when you always pass same value
                      @"someKey" : @YES
                      // if you want to pass some boolean variable
                      @"anotherKey" : @(someVariable)
                      };
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[dic setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:TRUE]  forKey:@"Pratik"];
[dic setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:FALSE] forKey:@"Sachin"];

if ([dic[@"Pratik"] boolValue])
{
    NSLog(@"Boolean is TRUE for 'Pratik'");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Boolean is FALSE for 'Pratik'");
}

if ([dic[@"Sachin"] boolValue])
{
    NSLog(@"Boolean is TRUE for 'Sachin'");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Boolean is FALSE for 'Sachin'");
}
```

*The output will be as following:*

Boolean is **TRUE** for '**Pratik**'

Boolean is **FALSE** for '**Sachin**'

Comment: You can also do `[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]` and `[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]`.